# Technological Animal Control

Tags: technology, fauna, control

In various TV series and movies villains or organisations have been shown to control animals through technological or cybernetic means, such as the future predators in Primeval. These creatures have technological implants that allow them to be controlled remotely by one individual from a tablet. Theoretically, how could this technology work?

Requirements:

- Allow complete control of the organisms motor functions, it doesn't have to affect natural bodily functions (heart rate, blood pressure, etc.)
- Be able to be controlled remotely, possible through radio waves or some other means
- Must be able to work or interface with a wide variety of creatures including animals like higher mammals, reptiles, fish, insects and other creatures (not including humans)

[image: Controlled Future Predators]

Comment: So the device has to work on mammals but not humans? That could be difficult. I can think of a few ways you could do this but they would all also effect humans.

Comment: I think he meant that it has to work on ... - but it doesn't need to work on humans. As in "when you get it to work and it cant affect humans I don't care  I just need it to work on these animals"

Comment: Yes @Soan i meant that i don't care if it works on humans it just has to work on  most animals.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly, we already have the necessary technology. The problem is the fine tuning. You need a variety of animals of the same species to experiment on. Then you build a little computer chip right at the nerves that control muscle groups, preferably in the brainstem or even better the motor cortex, as you'd only need one implant. 
Next step would be to let the animals live and move, while the implants log all neural stimuli. These have to be compared to the actual movements of the animals.
When you have the data, the implants can be used to give stimuli and cancel natural ones.

I don't know if this would actually work with insects and mollusks as they have a different nerve system. You would need at least four implants on a single cockroach. You need one for every brain or ganglion.

It works by sticking really little electrodes into the axons or brain/ganglion areas and feeding it electrodes. And thus it would look like a microchip with done kind of battery and little metallic stings all around.

Comment: Pigeons too!  https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/1544015/Scientists-develop-remote-controlled-pigeon.html

Answer (score 6):

[We already have working remote control for bugs](https://www.bugs.com/blog/remote-control-cockroaches/) and all creatures with a spine would simply need an implant at the spine.

Somehow you would have to know which impulses to give to which nerve and with that your remote control would already work.

Thats everything you wanted to know right?